# Android Textview cut part of letter if text too long

Tags: android, textview, xamarin.android

I want to make TextView looks like this

[image: Two TextViews, one under another]

where the black part is the TextView with smaller width above the grey one. It is some kind of progress bar. The interesting part is that this approach works on 6.0.1 and it worked on 5.1.1 without any special preferences. But it stopped working on Lollipop without any changes in code, and now TextView shows only complete letters, without cutting to parts (e.g. in that case black text will be only "Or")

Edited:

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp">
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleselected"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Changing progress:

```
titleSelected.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where the black part is the TextView with smaller width above the grey one. It is some kind of progress bar.

Instead of changing `layout_width` of `TextView`, you can change the `right` of `TextView`'s `ClipBounds` like below:

```
[Activity(Label = "ChangingText", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button btnClick;
    TextView titleselected;
    Rect drawingRect;
    int width;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        btnClick = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClick);
        titleselected = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titleselected);
        width = 1;
        btnClick.Click += BtnClick_Click;
    }

    private void BtnClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawingRect == null) {
            drawingRect = new Rect();
            titleselected.GetDrawingRect(drawingRect);
        }
        titleselected.ClipBounds = new Rect(0, 0, width++, drawingRect.Bottom);
    }
}
```

And Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp">

<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textColor="#C1C7C9"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleselected"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClick"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me"
    android:layout_marginTop="50sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it works well.

Comment: Yes, it works. I had to call `View.Invalidate()` after changing `ClipBounds` to see result on the device.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using this sample code and modify it according to your requirement

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sample extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acitivity_sample);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Spannable text = new SpannableStringBuilder("Loading..");
    setSpan(tv, text);
    tv.setText(text);
}

private void setSpan(TextView tv, Spannable text) {
    int blueColor = 0xff0000ff;
    int redColor = 0xffff0000;
    ForegroundColorSpan blue = new ForegroundColorSpan(blueColor);
    ForegroundColorSpan red = new ForegroundColorSpan(redColor);
    HalfColorApply o = new HalfColorApply("o", tv, blueColor, redColor);
    text.setSpan(blue, 0, 1, 0);
    text.setSpan(o, 1, 2, 0);
    text.setSpan(red, 3, text.length(), 0);
}

class HalfColorApply extends DynamicDrawableSpan {
    private final static String TAG = "DrawableSpanTest";
    Picture mPicture;

    public HalfColorApply(String text, TextView tv, int c0, int c1) {
        super(ALIGN_BASELINE);
        mPicture = new Picture();
        TextPaint p = tv.getPaint();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        float width = p.measureText(text);
        float height = bounds.height();
        float y = height;
        Canvas c = mPicture.beginRecording((int) width, (int) height);
        c.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
        // c.drawColor(0x[masked]);
        p = new TextPaint(p);
        p.setColor(c0);
        c.clipRect(0, 0, width / 2, height, Region.Op.REPLACE);
        c.drawText(text, 0, y, p);
        p.setColor(c1);
        c.clipRect(width / 2, 0, width, height, Region.Op.REPLACE);
        c.drawText(text, 0, y, p);
        c.restore();
        mPicture.endRecording();
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        PictureDrawable d = new PictureDrawable(mPicture);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, mPicture.getWidth(), mPicture.getHeight());
        return d;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah,  spannable string gives us ability to change style for symbols, but I need to have like half letter black and another half grey.

Comment: @llia check this code and i did this programtically

Comment: I have only width for black text, I don't know what letter exactly I need to fill with different colors as well as exact ratio for this letter.